# Dependency issues when trying to install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, qgis

I was trying to install qgis..

http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu

So when I ran...

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

I got the error below...

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-qgis is already the newest version.
qgis is already the newest version.
qgis-plugin-grass is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up qgis-providers (1:2.18.9+13jessie) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:2.18.9+13jessie); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 1:2.18.9+13jessie); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f

```
Setting up qgis-providers (1:2.18.9+13jessie) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:2.18.9+13jessie); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 1:2.18.9+13jessie); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-grass
```

Comment: Please post the exact command you entered and the full, verbatim output, formatted as code with the `{}` button. That error is completely generic and unhelpful (afaik dpkg only has one error code)

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the error message `/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, you need to install libmysqlclient18.

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04, then `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient18`.

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04, then libmysqlclient18 is not available anymore (replaced by libmysqlclient20). You may follow the answer at https://superuser.com/questions/1101426/installing-libmysqlclient18-on-ubuntu-16-04