# Installing qgis in ubuntu 18.04 error with sqlite tables, can no longer use apt

Tags: package-management, dependencies, sqlite3, qgis

I'm getting the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install grass grass-dev qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
grass-dev is already the newest version (7.4.0-1).
python-qgis is already the newest version (1:3.4.2+28bionic).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  qgis-providers
Suggested packages:
  gpsbabel
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  grass qgis qgis-plugin-grass qgis-providers
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/12.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 22.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package qgis-providers.
(Reading database ... 398057 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../qgis-providers_1%3a3.4.2+28bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qgis-providers (1:3.4.2+28bionic) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qgis.
Preparing to unpack .../qgis_1%3a3.4.2+28bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qgis (1:3.4.2+28bionic) ...
Selecting previously unselected package qgis-plugin-grass.
Preparing to unpack .../qgis-plugin-grass_1%3a3.4.2+28bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking qgis-plugin-grass (1:3.4.2+28bionic) ...
Selecting previously unselected package grass.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/grass_7.4.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking grass (7.4.0-1) ...
Setting up grass (7.4.0-1) ...
Setting up qgis-providers (1:3.4.2+28bionic) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 installed qgis-providers package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.4.2+28bionic); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 1:3.4.2+28bionic); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Why is it failing on something to do with sqlite tables?

I followed this:
[Dependency issues when trying to install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925625/dependency-issues-when-trying-to-install-qgis-python-qgis-qgis-plugin-grass)

And trying to install:

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Produces the same error about qgis for some reason.

This seems to have permanently messed up my system.  Anything I try to install produces this error.

## Edit for debug

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20
libgdal20: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20
```

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -S /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20` and `ldd /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20` to the question. Also note that your install command end with success on clean Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS VM without PPAs. It opens `qgis` and reports that it has 2.18 version. Do you have any PPAs added to the system?

Comment: Thanks, @N0rbert.  ldd seems to have a lot of output but `ldd /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20 grep | gdal` returns nothing

Comment: Please share full output of `ldd /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20` and `apt-cache policy libgdal20`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your libsqlite3 was built without the switch:

```
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA
```

which libgda1.so.20 expects.

Comment: That's useful info (can't see how you figured it!), but it would be great if you could advise what OP can do about it...